# Source that one doesn't challenge someone ready to humiliate himself to ask for tzedakah

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzedakah-charity

I seem to remember reading that one doesn't challenge someone ready to humiliate himself to ask for tzedakah, but I can't find the source.

The closest I am getting is the Rambam ([MT Matnot Aniyim 7:6](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/986708/jewish/Matnot-Aniyim-Chapter-7.htm))

> When a poor person whose identity is unknown says: "I am hungry,
>   provide me with food," we do not investigate whether he is a deceiver.
>   Instead, we provide him with sustenance immediately.

but that only applies to food since there is urgency.

and [7:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/986708/jewish/Matnot-Aniyim-Chapter-7.htm)

> It is forbidden to turn away a poor person who asks [for charity]
>   empty-handed.

**Does the idea that one doesn't challenge someone if he is ready to humiliate himself by begging exist as a formal *halacha*? What is its source?**

Comment: A similar idea about not challenging (investigating) a beggar exposed to humiliation is the opinion of Rav Huna ([BB 9a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.9a.6?with=all&lang=bi)), though the *halachah* follows Rav Yehudah (the source for Ramabam).

Comment: On *Purim*, כל הפושט יד נותנים לו.